# Reading pixel aspect ratio of TIF image in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, tiff, jai

I am reading in and processing TIF images using ImageIO and JAI. The results are all working perfectly, except that a number of the TIF images do not have square pixels. The aspect ratio of the pixels is being lost during the processing so the resulting image looks stretched.

I found this question which reads out the resolution in C#: [Change tiff pixel aspect ratio to square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890244/change-tiff-pixel-aspect-ratio-to-square) but I cannot find any equivalent in java.

Does anyone know how either to read the horizontal and vertical resolution (not size) of a BufferedImage and/or TIF Image in Java or cause JAI to scale the image as it loads it so that the resulting pixels are square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of Googling and trying things I think I have found a solution.

```
    IIOMetadata iiom = ir.getImageMetadata(i);
    TIFFDirectory dir = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(iiom);

    TIFFField fieldXRes = dir.getTIFFField(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION);
    TIFFField fieldYRes = dir.getTIFFField(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION);

    int xRes = fieldXRes.getAsInt(0);
    int yRes = fieldYRes.getAsInt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also get the same values from the [Standard Metadata](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html), if you don't want to rely on the JAI API (or TIFF format specifics at all).

The `Dimension` element has the child elements `HorizontalPixelSize` and `VerticalPixelSize` which should be equivalent to the values you got from the TIFF tags above, as well as a `PixelAspectRatio` you could use directly.